# How do I query Impala from rust?

Tags: rust, odbc, impala

How do I query a Impala database from Rust code.

I did look at SQLx, but it does not support this dialect. I also had a brief look into odbc-api crate, but I was not able to connect either. Maybe the ODBC driver is missing, but I do not know how to tell this crate to use the driver.

Comment: Impala connects with most tools using Cloudera ODBC driver. Pls check if its instatalled and if you can use it ?

Comment: Yes, `odbc-api` crate is the solution you're looking for. You'll need the driver first, install it from official [downloads](https://www.cloudera.com/downloads/connectors/impala/odbc/2-6-17.html) section.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Since I am on arch I had to create an install package for the rpm file and add the odbc configuration under /etc/odbc.ini